# Zedboard_Adv7511_HDMI Project Vivado Tcl building error

Tags: vivado, zynq

When I was trying to run ADI's project https://wiki.analog.com/resources/fpga/xilinx/kc705/adv7511 in Vivado 2017.4, then got this message

`ERROR: [BD 41-1075] Cannot create address segment for </axi_hdmi_clkgen/s_axi/reg0> in </sys_ps7/Data> at 0x079000000 [ 4G ].  The proposed address exceeds the base address limitations <0x40000000 [ 1G ]> of the interface(s) </sys_ps7/M_AXI_GP0> through which this peripheral is accessed by this address space`

Then I tried to allocate every address of every peripheral by using the auto address assignment in Address Editter.

[image]

Then I altered zed_system_bd.tcl

[image]

but still got the same kind of error.  According to `ZYNQ_TRM`, GP0 mapping at 0x4000_0000 to 0x7FFF_FFFF. 
Can anyone please tell me what I can do?

Comment: Removed the `tcl` tag as your usage of the Tcl language itself seems correct on the face of it; this is some sort of application-level issue (or hardware? I don't know Vivado at all.)

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I am having a similar issue when attempting to build this project: https://wiki.analog.com/resources/fpga/docs/hdl/xcomm2ip